# How to merge data from two tables using a select statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables with the similar kind of the columns.

**TableA**

```
Col1 Col2
1    ABC
2    BCD
3    CDE
```

**TableB**

```
Col3 Col4
1    EFG
2    FGH
3    GHI
```

I wanted to merge both table in one table using the select query, output should like below:

```
ID Col1 Col2
1  1    ABC
2  2    BCD
3  3    CDE
4  1    EFG
5  2    FGH
6  3    GHI
```

OR

```
Col1 Col2
1     ABC
2     BCD
3     CDE
4     EFG
5     FGH
6     GHI
```

Can anyone provide me the query for above output:

Note: I wanted the unique ID as the col1 in place of repeated IDs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work.

Comment: Did you saw my new answer. The output is as required by you

Comment: @Eshwer: Tell me if my updated answer accomplishes your question

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Col1,
       Col2
FROM   TableA
UNION
SELECT Col3 AS Col1,
       Col4 AS Col2
FROM   TableB;
```

**EDIT**

If you need a new autoincrementing ID column, you have to add it with ROW_NUMBER()

```
--  Create test table
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
Col1 int
,Col2 CHAR(4)
);

-- Insert data
INSERT INTO Table1(Col1, Col2)
SELECT '1', 'ABC' UNION ALL
SELECT '2', 'BCD' UNION ALL
SELECT '3', 'CDE';

CREATE TABLE Table2
(
Col3 int
,Col4 CHAR(4)
);

-- Insert data
INSERT INTO Table2(Col3, Col4)
SELECT '1', 'EFG' UNION ALL
SELECT '2', 'FGR' UNION ALL
SELECT '3', 'GHI';

 SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Col2) ROW_NUM
  FROM (
        select Col1, Col2 from Table1
        union all  
        select Col3, Col4 from Table2
       ) a
       ORDER BY ROW_NUM

-- Drop table
DROP TABLE Table1
DROP TABLE Table2
```

Comment: Hi, with this query the output will like Col1 Col2
1     ABC
1     EFG
2     BCD
2     FGH
3     CDE
3     GHI

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION. Please see the link:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need.use row_number() over

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col2) ROW_NUM
 FROM (
    select col1, col2 from Table1  
    Union all  
    select col3 as col1, col4 as col2 from Table2
   ) a
order by a.col1,a.col2
```

[**Sql Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8bd4f/2)

Comment: Not coming proper out put

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION command:

Try this:

```
SELECT Col1 as Col1, Col2 as Col2 FROM TableA
UNION 
SELECT Col3, Col4 FROM TableB
```

OR

```
SELECT Col1 as Col1, Col2 as Col2 FROM TableA
UNION ALL
SELECT Col3, Col4 FROM TableB
```

You must use the first query if you want to discard all duplicated rows.

You must use the second query if you want to show duplicated rows.

If you are sure, not exists duplicated rows, use always UNION ALL because don't apply a silent DISTINCT clause.

**EDIT**

I've updated my answer in this way:

I've used DENSE_RANK() function to renumber your ID field based on a fake field (always valued 0)

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY fake ORDER BY col1, col2 DESC) AS id,
T.col1, T.col2
FROM 
    (SELECT Col1 as col1, Col2 as col2, 0 as fake
    FROM TableA 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col3, col4, 0
    FROM TableB) as T
```

go to [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/221af/8/0)
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/221af/8/0

Comment: Already used not working, I want all rows of both table but the ID should be as unique when display